# Warning about "Untrusted Software Launcher"

Tags: software-installation

I've installed ToupLite from Touptek.com as software for my microscope camera. When I try to run it, I get "Untrusted Software Launcher" and no opportunity to run it.

1. does this mean that Ubuntu detects a Trojan, etc.?
2. what do I suggest that ToupTek do to remedy this?

Comment: ToupTek contact is ToupTek Eivira <tphz@touptek.com>

Comment: Exactly what error message do you get, and how do you run it?

Comment: Installation from command line puts several files in ~/usr/local/ToupLite  and an icon ToupLite.desktop on Desktop. Double-clicking the latter gets a pop-up "Untrusted Software Launcher" is not marked as trusted. Dialog has a Cancel option only.

Answer (score 0):

That .desktop file belongs to 'root' user. So, you may duplicate that file and simply click on the new file that you own. Then, "Trust and Launch".